# Como posso utilizar dois models em uma mesma view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

tenho uma View que tem uma dropdownlist e uma text box. Essa dropdownlist está retornando seus itens de um model.
Depois de preencher esses dois objetos, faço uma requisição que irá trazer uns resultados que quero mostrar abaixo, porém estou carregando outro model, e parece que o mvc não permite isso.
Vocês saberiam de uma solução pra esse caso? Vou colocar meus códigos aqui.

Obrigado.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home page";

            TiposEventos eventos = new TiposEventos();
            ViewBag.listaEventos = eventos.GetAll().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.idTipoEvento.ToString(),
                Text = x.nomeTipoEvento
            });

            Results res = new Results();
            res.listEndossos = null;
            res.listSinistros = null;
            res.listTotais = null;


            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string idTipoEvento, string dtAnoMes)
        {
            List<TipoEvento> eventos = new TiposEventos().GetAll().ToList();

            string nome = eventos.Find(e => e.idTipoEvento == Convert.ToInt32(idTipoEvento)).nomeTipoEvento;
            nome = nome.Replace("\r\n", "");

            ViewBag.listaEventos = new SelectList(eventos, "idTipoEvento", "nomeTipoEvento", idTipoEvento);

            Results res = new Results();
            res.listEndossos = RetornaEndossos(nome, dtAnoMes);
            res.listSinistros = RetornaSinistros(nome, dtAnoMes);
            res.listTotais = RetornaDadosTotais(nome, dtAnoMes);

            return View();
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Evento:
                    @model TipoEvento
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idTipoEvento, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listaEventos, "Selecione um evento")

                </p>
                <p>
                    Ano/Mês:
                    <input type="text" name="dtAnoMes" id="dtAnoMes" placeholder="____/__" maxlength="7" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Gerar</button>
                </p>
            }
        </div>
    </section>

}
@model Results
<h3>Analítico:</h3>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Num SAP</th>
          <th>Valor SAP</th>
          <th>Num CRC</th>
          <th>Valor CRC</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

      @foreach (var item in @Model.listEndossos)
      {
          <tr>
              <th scope="row">@item.numEndossoSap</th>
              <td>@item.valorSap</td>
              <td>@item.numEndossoCRC</td>
              <td>@item.valorCRC</td>
          </tr> 
      }

      @foreach (var item in @Model.listSinistros)
      {
          <tr>
              <th scope="row">@item.numSinistroSap</th>
              <td>@item.valorSap</td>
              <td>@item.numSinistroCRC</td>
              <td>@item.valorCRC</td>
          </tr> 
      }

</tbody>
</table>
<h3>Total:</h3>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Ano/Mês</th>
          <th>Valor SAP</th>
          <th>Valor CRC</th>
          <th>Divergência</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>

      @foreach (var item in @Model.listTotais)
      {
          <tr>
              <th scope="row">@item.dtAnoMes</th>
              <td>@item.valorSapTotal</td>
              <td>@item.valorCRCTotal</td>
              <td>@item.divergencia</td>
          </tr> 
      }

</tbody>
</table>
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

Consegui resolver utilizando ViewData, porém também funcionaria utilizando ViewBag ou TempData.
Na view não precisa passar o model, apenas a viewdata que criou no controller.

View

```
@if (ViewData["DadosTotais"] != null)
      {     
          foreach (var item in ViewData["DadosTotais"] as List<ProjetoContabil.Models.Entities.DadosTotais>)
```

Controller

```
ViewData["DadosTotais"] = res.listTotais;
```

Comment: Guilherme, é recomendável colocar respostas para as próprias perguntas. Pode ajudar alguém com seu mesmo problema no futuro ;-)